# rsyslog doesn`t open tcp listener

Tags: linux, security, logging, rsyslog

I am configuring rsyslog on a Linux server and want to configure it with TLS secure transport, I follow many documentation including rsyslog official guide (https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/tutorials/tls.html), the thing is that I can see udp port listening, but tcp doesn't and not getting errors on configuration validation, so I am blind and not seeing why tcp port is not listening, I try low and high ports and nothing, I am attaching configuration file that I use last time and the configuration validation output, thanks for any help!

```
module(load="imuxsock")
module(
load="imtcp"
StreamDriver.Name="gtls"
StreamDriver.Mode="1"
StreamDriver.Authmode="anon"
)
input(type="imtcp" port="11514")
module(load="imudp")
input(type="imudp" port="1514")
global(
DefaultNetstreamDriver="gtls"
DefaultNetstreamDriverCAFile="/var/ossec/agentless/rsyslog/ca.pem"
DefaultNetstreamDriverCertFile="/var/ossec/agentless/rsyslog/server/cert.pem"
DefaultNetstreamDriverKeyFile="/var/ossec/agentless/rsyslog/server-key.pem"
)
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat
$RepeatedMsgReduction on
$FileOwner syslog
$FileGroup adm
$FileCreateMode 0640
$DirCreateMode 0755
$Umask 0022
$PrivDropToUser syslog
$PrivDropToGroup syslog
$WorkDirectory /var/spool/rsyslog
$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf


And validation:
# rsyslogd -N6
rsyslogd: version 8.16.0, config validation run (level 6), master config /etc/rsyslog.conf
rsyslogd: End of config validation run. Bye.


Netstat output:
# netstat -na |grep 514
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1514            0.0.0.0:*
udp6       0      0 :::1514                 :::*
```

Comment: Try to run it in debug mode.
`export RSYSLOG_DEBUG=debug;
rsyslogd -d` to help troubledhoot it

Comment: And what distribution it is. Is it configured with some MAC like selinux or apparnor ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers, the problem apparently was not in the rsyslog configuration, but in Wazuh, the software that was trying to receive the logs of the rsyslog, what I did was change the configuration of the ossec.conf of Wazuh and the open port, create another remote control, one with safe value and one with syslog value and it worked, thanks for all the support as always !!! Hugs and take care